# What happened to my virtualenv

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualenv

I properly restarted vagrant VM(ubuntu). After reboot first ALIAS that I used to activate virtualenv wasn't found. When I manually activated it and tried to use python I get following errors:

```
(virtualenv)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ python
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f7c3fc4e740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This virtualenv is in vagrant shared directory, and everything seems to be in place there.

This happened after I updated manjaro(arch) host. Not sure how that could affect vagrant VM...

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please issue `echo $PYTHONHOME` and `echo $PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Both respond with empty line.

Comment: So your working directory is `/vargant` and you activate virtualenv like `vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ source bin/activate`. If you open bin/activate file there should be VIRTUAL_ENV varialbe. Could you please show what it set to. It should be like /vargant.

Comment: Yes, this one is: VIRTUAL_ENV="/vagrant/virtualenv"

Comment: Ok. and what about `echo $PATH`